# Why does this code work in Firefox but not in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I cannot get this script to work in Chrome, it works fine in Firefox. What it does is place a "clear" button at the top of each column in Tweetdeck. It shows the button but nothing happens when it is clicked.

```
  // ==UserScript==
    // @name           TweetDeck Clear Button
    // @namespace      http://dvdbng.com
    // @description    Adds a clear column button directly accesible
    // @include        https://web.tweetdeck.com/*
    // ==/UserScript==

    var $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery;
//Places the "clean" button on top of header 
    unsafeWindow.TD_mustaches["column/column_header.mustache"] = unsafeWindow.TD_mustaches["column/column_header.mustache"].replace('<div class="options-nav">','<div class="options-nav"><a class="GS_clean">clean</a>');   
    $(document.body).delegate(".GS_clean","click",function(){
//This does navigation to get to the "Clear Column" button
        $(this).parents(".column")
            .find("a[data-action=options]").click().end()
            .find("input[data-action=clear]").click().end()
            .find("a[data-action=options]").click()
    });
```

Comment: Try `alert(typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery);` in Chrome. If it says `undefined`, Chrome isn't letting you access jQuery like that. It happened to me a few days ago as well.

Comment: When I put that line in after the .find block of code it gives me an alert box saying "function", so it seems to respond to the click but doesn't clear the column.